# Can sudo use my existing aliases?

Tags: terminal, bash, sudo

How can I let `sudo` use my existing aliases in my .bash_profile (or .bashrc, .profile …)?
For example I want to be able to use `ll` instead of `ls -laGF` as `sudo`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Sudo draws from the root account and won't consult your user's `~/.bash_profile`.

But you can workaround this problem by adding the following alias to your profile:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

*Note the space after the command. From then on, `sudo` will work normally and you'll be able to use your user's aliases without issue (both normally and with root privileges).

---

**Explanation:** http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases says:

> If the last character of the alias value is a space or tab character, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

Comment: I suppose you meant to type `alias sudo='sudo ', since that works! Change your answer accordingly and I will accept it.

Comment: @Asmus yes sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

alias sudo='sudo su -i ENV=/home/myuser/.profile'